# Mastermind game in Python - overcounting problem

Tags: python

I am trying to make a mastermind game in Python without using custom built functions and more advanced concepts, using only conditionals and loops. So far, I have this:

```
import random

print("*" * 100 + "\n" + "*" * 100 + "\n" + "---> Welcome to the  MASTERMIND game!!! <---\n" + "*" * 100 + "\n" + "*" * 100 + "\n") 

colors = ["white", "black", "yellow", "red", "green", "blue"]

# right_position = 0
# wrong_position = 0  I made a mistake and put these 2 variables here...this will never work because I got outputs like wrong position is equal to 6. Instead, they need to be reseted every time, that's why they need to go inside of the loop

computer_color1 = random.choice(colors)
computer_color2 = random.choice(colors)
computer_color3 = random.choice(colors)
computer_color4 = random.choice(colors)

# print(f"{computer_color1} --- {computer_color2} --- {computer_color3} --- {computer_color4}\n" ) # computer choice, we can print this to confirm that our program works correctly


for user_try in range(1,11):
    print(f"This is your {user_try} try.")

    right_position = 0
    wrong_position = 0
    not_exists = 0
    


    user_color1 = input("Please select the 1st color: ")
    user_color2 = input("Please select the 2nd color: ")
    user_color3 = input("Please select the 3rd color: ")
    user_color4 = input("Please select the 4th color: ")

    if user_color1 == computer_color1:
        right_position += 1
    elif user_color1 in [computer_color2, computer_color3, computer_color4]:
        wrong_position += 1
    else:
        not_exists += 1

    if user_color2 == computer_color2:
        right_position += 1
    elif user_color2 in [ computer_color1, computer_color3, computer_color4]:
        wrong_position += 1
    else:
        not_exists += 1


    if user_color3 == computer_color3:
        right_position += 1
    elif user_color3 in [ computer_color1, computer_color2,  computer_color4]:
        wrong_position += 1
    else:
        not_exists += 1

    if user_color4 == computer_color4:
        right_position += 1
    elif user_color4 in [ computer_color1, computer_color2, computer_color3]:
        wrong_position += 1
    else:
        not_exists += 1

    print("\u2714Correct position: ", right_position)
    print("\u166EWrong position: ", wrong_position)
    print("\u2205Out of 4 colors from the computer combination , the number of user colors that does not exist is: ", not_exists)

    if right_position == 4:
        print("\n\ngame over!!! YOU WON")
        print("The computer correct color is: ")
        print(f"{computer_color1} --- {computer_color2} --- {computer_color3} --- {computer_color4}\n")
        break


    print(f"user combination of colors after the {user_try} is: ")
    print(f"{user_color1} --- {user_color2} --- {user_color3} --- {user_color4}\n" )

print("Computer color combination: ")
print(f"{computer_color1} --- {computer_color2} --- {computer_color3} --- {computer_color4}\n")
```

The problem is that `wrong_position` variable is overcounting, and I do not know how to correct that. For example, if the correct color combination that the computer generated is:

*red --- white --- white --- blue*

and for the first try, from 1st to 4th color, I enter respectively:

*blue, blue, blue, blue*

the output that I get is:

✔Correct position:  1

᙮ Wrong position:  3

while it should be:

✔Correct position:  1

᙮Wrong position:  0

How can I make this work?

Comment: what mean `Wrong position`? and why it should be `0` even if answer was wrong three times?

Comment: [@Marko Savic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8222481/marko-savic) `Wrong position` needs to be defined by you. There are a few that can make sense and the rules you decided on are not obvious in this example. If I guess one "yellow" in the wrong place, and there are two "yellow"s that I did not guess, is `Wrong position` 1, or 2, or even 0?

Comment: @rzlvmp Wrong position is a color that exists but is in the wrong position; second question: because it counts the number of misplaced colors that exist. In my example, the 3 blue colors do not exist but the program adds them to the variable *wrong_position* .

Answer (score 0):

If you want the wrong position to be zero *(in this case)* you would have to first check if anything is on the correct position and if so discard it from future check. Then check if anything is on wrong position (this could still be problematic in some cases i'm not sure how exactly mastermind game works), and everything that is still left could be counted towards `not_exists`.